# Does removing the battery while connected to power extend battery life?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

On regular Windows notebooks people generally remove their battery packs when connected to a power source, in order to extend battery life.

Does a similar approach work on the Mac?

Comment: It's interesting that you say people "generally" remove the battery when on mains power: nobody at my company of 500+ does that, and I've never seen anybody do it, even at university. (Not that I don't believe you, but it's interesting how different people's ideas of "normal" can differ.)

Comment: No, you don't need to remove your battery. Just keep it away from excessive heat and avoid leaving it in a constant state of a 100% charge (this means using it from time to time) and you'll be fine. Stop worrying about it!

Comment: Maybe you can see here: https://github.com/alaneuler/batteryKid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OSX has protection built-in to keep from continuously charging the battery, you shouldn't remove it, there is no benefit.

Part of that protection is that if you plug in your laptop >95% charge, it won't actually charge the battery, and will run off of the power adapter.

Comment: Is there a reference about the built-in protection?

Answer (score 8):

On many recent Macs, you cannot remove the battery (at least not easily), so this simply wouldn't work.

In general, it's kind of pointless to do that, as you're negating a benefit of having the battery: if the power goes out or the cable gets pulled (especially if it's a magnetic cable), you lose power just like a desktop would.

Ultimately, I would recommend not bothering in either the Mac or Windows case.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of MacOS notice when the notebook tends to be run with power connected and stops charging at somewhere between 80 and 90 %, which protect the long-term health of the battery.  [image: battery information from the menu bar: 87 % Power Source: Power Adapter Charging On Hold (Rarely Used On Battery) Charge to Full Now]